# How do I prove a limit of multivariable functions using epsilon-delta definitions?

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I need to prove that
$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (3, 1)} x + y^2 = 4.$$
by using formal epsilon-delta definitions of multivariate limits. I understand that this is the case if and only if for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a corresponding $\delta > 0$ such that for every $(x, y)$ satisfying
$$0 < \sqrt{(x-3)^2 + (y-1)^2} < \delta$$
it is true that
$$|x + y^2 - 4| < \varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: write $|x+y^2-4| = |(x-3) + (y^2-1)| \leq |x-3| + |y^2-1|$. Then explain how you can find a $\delta$ that ensures that $0 < \sqrt{(x-3)^2 + (y-1)^2} < \delta$ implies $|x-3| < \epsilon/2$ and $|y^2-1| < \epsilon/2$.